# Python - How to run a loop inside another loop with range?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I don't know if my title really encompasses what I am trying to accomplish. I have a list of email addresses and I want to only email about 50 a day. So I have made the following scripts neither are working:

```
email_list = ['first@email.com','second@email.com','third@email.com','fourth@email.com','fifth@email.com']
for num in range(0, 2):
    for email in email_list:
        print(email)
    time.sleep(2)

email_list = ['first@email.com','second@email.com','third@email.com','fourth@email.com','fifth@email.com']
    for email in email_list:
        for num in range(0, 2):
            print(email)
        time.sleep(2)
```

So what I would like to do is run the script for 50 times, then wait for a specific period of time then run the next cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
email_list =['first@email.com','second@email.com','third@email.com','fourth@email.com','fifth@email.com']
send = 0
for email in email_list:
    print(email)
    send += 1
    if send % 50 == 0:
        time.sleep(2)
```

This will wait 2 second every 50 mails printed

Comment: Looks like this works out of both of the answers I received. Why is it working with `if send % 50 == 0`?

Comment: the variable `send` counts how many mails were printed. `send % 50` is the remainder of dividing `send` by 50, so it's 0 every 50 mails